# Provided script uses jQuery's $, but drupal site has noConflict enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7

I have a Drupal 7 site (with jquery-update installed, FWIW).  jQuery seems to be referenced by the jQuery object instead of $.  This is well documented at https://www.drupal.org/node/171213.

I am trying to make use of a provided script to meet some specific requirements.

The script provided makes use of the $ object, and so I get "TyperError: $ is not a function".

The HTML and script provided looks like:

```
<div id="grid"><span class="grid-load-error">There was an error loading the interactive grid.</span></div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//site.com/tool.js">
</script>
```

On page load, I get the TypeError message.

I have tried to wrap the loading of the script in a closure:

```
<div id="grid"><span class="grid-load-error">There was an error loading the interactive grid.</span></div> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $(function() {
            // console.log($('#grid').html());
            $.getScript("//site.com/tool.js");
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

I know that $ works within the closure - the commented console.log() generates the correct output when uncommented.

I assumed that $.getScript() would fail, as https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/ tells me that the script is executed in the global context (which, if I understand closures correctly $ isn't global here).

Is there a way that I can include this script from the source, or should I edit it to replace "$" with "jQuery"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.getScript` is a shortcut for `$.ajax()` and then jquery being nice just appending the script to `<head>` for you. However in your case this won't work as you already found out. So, just create your own `$.getScript`

Just fetch the script, and then append it to your own `<script>` tag and wrap the contents of the fetched script in an [iffe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

```js
<script id="myLib"></script>
<script>
    (function ($){
        //$.getScript('./tool.js');
        $.ajax({
            url: './tool.js',
            dataType: "text", //force script response to be treated as plain text
            success: function(data) {
                var myLib = '(function ($){' + data + '}(jQuery));';
                $('#myLib').html(myLib);
            }
        });
    }(jQuery));
</script>
```

Your script should work fine now. Just make sure that

```
<script id="myLib"></script>
```

Comes after jQuery is defined on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your external script with:

```
(function($) {

})(jQuery);
```